# Resizing and Calculating sizes of Elements depending on count and fixed wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery

lets say you have a block (div) with a size of 100px X 100px.

Now I pass into this block one image with the size of 100 X 100px. The same size, so it fits.

Now the question: What is the best approach if I have 2, 3 or 6 images and I want them to appear in the 100 X 100px box.

Example: 1 Image -> 100 * 100, 2 Images 50 * 50 each, 9 images 33% * 33% each.

The images will always have same width and height.

Thanks for any tipps!

Answer (score -1):

you answerd your own question :-)

`imageWidth = containerWidth/amountImages`

For your "Tile" Solution you can

`imageWidth = containerWidth/amountImagesInRow`

`imageHeight = containerHeight/amountImagesInColumn`

If you want to determine how many rows/col you need: 
define a minimum width an do some kind of

`for(...){`

`if imageWidth < minWidth`

`amountImages -= 1;`

`imageWidth = containerWidth/amountImages`

`}`

`imagesInRow = amountImages;`

Comment: also, imageHeight = containerHeight/amountImages.

Comment: eh sorry guys, how would then, for 9 images, 30% X 30% work??? with your solution it would be something like 11.11%. I wouldnt ask if it would be this easy :)

Comment: Hi Luke, its still that easy :-)
What you want is some Kinde of Tiles. You can formulate the width as

imageWidth = containerWidth/amountImagesInRow
imageHeight = containerHeight/amountImagesInCol